# How to identify the reference genome assembly used to create a .hic file?

Tags: reference-genome, chromosome-capture, hi-c

I have a bunch of .hic files of different species. But, I don't know which reference genome assembly (e.g. GRCh37 or GRCh38 in the case of human genome) the genomic co-ordinates of the .hic file correspond to. So I wonder if there is any way to figure out the version of the reference genome assembly from a .hic file.

**Therefore, my question is**: Does .hic file contain metadata such as the version of reference genome assembly? If yes, then how could I access it?

(I could obtain the information I need by digging into the methods sections of each paper corresponding to each .hic file. But it would be much better if I could get that right-away from the .hic file.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out HiC file does store such metadata.

`straw` tool from Aiden Lab contains a script ([read_hic_header.py](https://github.com/aidenlab/straw/blob/master/python/read_hic_header.py)) that prints out the metadata from a given HiC file. Usage: `read_hic_header.py <hic file or URL> [verbose]`

In order to obtain the metadata in the form of a dictionary, one may consider using a function of the same tool that is currently available in my [fork](https://github.com/rraadd88/straw.git).

```
from straw import straw_module
straw_module.read_metadata(infile,verbose=False)

Args
    infile: str, path to the HiC file 
    verbose: bool, print the metadata if True else return the metadata
Returns
    metadata: dict, the metadata is returned if verbose is False. 
                Keys of the metadata: 
                HiC version, 
                Master index, 
                Genome ID (str), 
                Attribute dictionary (dict), 
                Chromosomes (dict), 
                chromosomes2length (dict), 
                Base pair-delimited resolutions (list), 
                Fragment-delimited resolutions (list).
```